# Why is my index view not working when I implement datepicker in my rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi I am new to rails and would really appreciate some help, I am using the jQuery datepicker, the show view works however the index view doesn't, i get "undefined method `start_date' for nil:NilClass" in my index.html.erb file.  Can you please let me know what is wrong with my index view and how i can fix it.  The following are included in my app:

**meetups_controller.rb**

```
def show

@meetup = Meetup.find(params[:id])

end

def index

@meetups = Meetup.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id).order('created_at DESC')

end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<h3>Title: <%= @meetup.title %></h3>

<p>Start date: <%= @meetup.start_date.strftime("%B %e,  %Y") %></p>

<p>Start time: <%= @meetup.start_time.strftime("%l:%M %P") %></p>

<p>End date: <%= @meetup.end_date.strftime("%B %e,  %Y") %></p>

<p>End time: <%= @meetup.end_time.strftime("%l:%M %P") %></p>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% if @meetups.any? %>

<% @meetups.each do |meetup| %>


<h3><%= link_to meetup.title, meetup_path(meetup) %></h3>

<p>Start date: <%= @meetup.start_date.strftime("%B %e,  %Y") %></p>

<p>Start time: <%= @meetup.start_time.strftime("%l:%M %P") %></p>

<p>End date: <%= @meetup.end_date.strftime("%B %e,  %Y") %></p>

<p>End time: <%= @meetup.end_time.strftime("%l:%M %P") %></p>
```

Comment: Please accept my answer by making the tick mark green if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `start_date' for nil:NilClass

You are **`looping`** through **`@meetups`** as **`meetup`** but you are giving **`@meetup`** in the **`loop`** instead of **`meetup`**.So is the error because there is no **`@meetup`** initialized in your **`index action`**.

This should work

```
<% @meetups.each do |meetup| %>

<h3><%= link_to meetup.title, meetup_path(meetup) %></h3>

<p>Start date: <%= meetup.start_date.strftime("%B %e,%Y") %></p>

<p>Start time: <%= meetup.start_time.strftime("%l:%M %P") %></p>

<p>End date  : <%= meetup.end_date.strftime("%B %e,%Y") %></p>

<p>End time  : <%= meetup.end_time.strftime("%l:%M %P") %></p>

<% end %>
```